# systemd integration

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, rhel, init

I was asked during an interview this ambiguous question, that I couldn't answer

> which one of this tools has not had functions integrated into `systemd`?

- udev
- consolekit
- sysvinit
- pam
- syslog

Comment: I'd guess that this question fails miserably at being any sort of a reliable indicator for hiring people.

Answer (score 0):

systemd is, among other things, a replacement for sysvinit. That means you wont run both tools at the same time. In fact, usually there is only one of them installed. So, sysvinit has no functions integrated into systemd.

`ConsoleKit` is AFAIK dead and replaced by `systemd-logind.service`. For this reason, you are right in judging the question as "ambiguous" when asked for only one tool.

The other components work together with systemd:

- `journalctl` and the syslog
- `systemd-udevd.service` is a systemd service
- PAM registers its sessions via the `systemd-logind.service`